# How do I restore old versions from previous commits and get my site to load on localhost?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git

I am trying to restore the settings from the commit "Testing Paperclip." Originally, the original version would show up in my local files, but not on localhost. Now, it won't load on my localhost. The rails c command was *just* working fine for me, but now my command line seems to be off. For example, when I enter "git status", it says "NameError: undefined local variable or method `status' for main:Object" and I *did* do the rails s command beforehand. On localhost, it says the error is this.

Migrations are pending. To resolve this issue, run: bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development

Yet, when I run this command, it never works. How can I get this working back to normal again? Are my changes completely restored? (I can't even tell since the page won't load)

Comment: So you've run `rake db:migrate` and still get the error? Are you able to run `rails s` now? Assuming that you've been using `git` with this app, make sure you're in the app's directory when executing `git` commands.

Answer (score 0):

By the message you are seeing ("NameError: undefined local variable or method `status' for main:Object"), I'm deducing that you are inside a `rails c` or an `irb` session. The `git` command need to be executed from you "normal" shell.

Check your prompt (the first characters that appear in the command line, where you can type commands), this will give you a hint if you are in a `rails c` session. If so, you will see something like: `irb(main):001:0>`.

In this case, just type exit, and you will be back to your normal shell and able to use `git` or execute other commands like the `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: I just tried doing that and I still have the same error. :/

Comment: Now it says this: could not obtain a database connection within 5.000 seconds (waited 5.000 seconds)